# How can I get this return data into dynamic arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

Working with regular javascript, I need to store info into an array for output where Cust ID is the same. So the result data:

**Tran ID**         **Name**                               **Cust ID**          **Brand**          **Tran Date**
16446       |     Denton Bible Church        |     8381        |      Epson     |      8/27/2009
124751    |     Denton Bible Church        |     8381     |       Da-Lite    |     10/27/2010

My javascript to get column data:

```
for ( var z = 0; z < records.length; z++ ) {
        var result = records[z];
        var columns = result.getAllColumns();
        var column = columns[3];
        var brands = result.getValue(column);
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','brands',brands);

        column = columns[2];
        var internalid = result.getValue(column);
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','internalid',internalid);

        column = columns[4];
        var orderdate = result.getValue(column);
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','orderdate',orderdate);

        var boresult = orderdate + "-" + brands;

        //The above would be inserted into the customer field for 1 customer

        //nlapiSetFieldValue('custentity28',brands + "-" + orderdate);
        nlapiSubmitField('customer', internalid, 'custentity28', boresult);
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','enter','enter');
          }
```

I'm using API from my accounting software so the functions may not make sense. Anyway, so I need to know how to say: For every Cust ID that is the same, create an array and store in the following format:

8/27/2009 - Epson
10/27/2010 - Da-Lite

You can see I tried to do that with the boresult variable but I think that would only be pulling in the first line right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should create an array outside the loop and just [`push`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) items into it:

```
var boresults = [];

for (var z = 0; z < records.length; z++) {

    // Some code here...        

    var boresult = orderdate + "-" + brands;
    boresults.push(boresult);

    // Some other code...
}
```